# В свою очередь

Tags: пунктуация

"В свою очередь(,) на него возлагается обязанность использовать средства защиты"
Нужна ли здесь запятая? И в каких случаях она нужна?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сочетание **в свою очередь** не выделяется запятыми, если оно употреблено в значении, близком к прямому или в значении «со своей стороны», например: *– А вы? – спросил он у шофера в свою очередь (т.е. когда наступила его очередь)*. В переносном же значении указанное сочетание обычно выделяется, например: *Различаются суффиксы существительных увеличительные и уменьшительные; в группе последних, в свою очередь, выделяются суффиксы уменьшительно-ласкательные*.
В вашем случае, на мой взгляд, выражение **в свою очередь** употреблено в переносном значении, является вводным со значением указания на связь мыслей, последовательность изложения и должно выделяться запятой. Однако меня смущает само предложение. Я бы написала: "В свою очередь, он обязан (обязуется) использовать средства защиты". Для более точной формулировки нужен контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я ошибаюсь (будь так, поправьте, если не в службу), но, на мой взгляд, пунктуация при сочетании *в свою очередь* - по крайней мере в текстах неофициального и неделового стилей - не должна становиться причиной усиленных размышлений на пределе возможностей.
Сочетание *в свою очередь* выделяется запятыми как вводное, если указывает на то, что данное высказывание связано по смыслу с предшествующим. В тех случаях, когда означенное сочетание не является вводным, оно играет роль обстоятельства в предложении. Обстоятельства, когда для этого нет более веских оснований, могут обособляться, если автор хочет выделить их интонационно, если они имеют значение попутного замечания и т. п.
Из этого можно сделать такой вывод: выделяйте - и не судимы будете. В большинстве случаев это правильный вывод.

Comment: 1)Нацкорпус - это, конечно, не орфографический справочник, но он представляет живую речь, а не придуманные или нужным образом подобранные иллюстрации к правилам. Поэтому заглядывать туда весьма полезно, и источники в нем весьма разнообразны.
2) Что я имею в виду? Фундаментальный закон русского синтаксиса - ни больше ни меньше. Слова и словосочетания - это строительный материал, из которых мы составляем фразы: любое предложение - это набор фраз, разделенных паузами.

Comment: Возьмем, к примеру, самое простое предложение: "ОнИ в свою очередь (пауза) сдавали торговые места в субарЕнду". Здесь оборот "в свою очередь" не обособляется, так как он пошел на построение первой фразы (это и называется «встроить оборот в предложение») .  А теперь распространим предложение: "Они, в свою очередь,  практически всегдА (пауза) сдавали торговые места в субарЕнду". Теперь для построения первой фразы оборот не нужен (появился другой стройматериал - наречие).

Comment: Оборот стал лишним, и его выносят на второй план, а предложение по-прежнему состоит из двух фраз (каждая фраза - одно тоническое ударение).

Comment: >Оборот стал лишним, и его выносят на второй план, а предложение по-прежнему состоит из двух фраз (каждая фраза - одно тоническое ударение).

Тоническое ударение... Мой ограниченный ум не способен оперировать подобными категориями, поэтому я могу лишь заметить, не претендуя на истину в последней инстанции, что в «нераспространенном» варианте предложения обстоятельство в свою очередь может быть опущено с таким же успехом, с каким это может быть сделано в «распространенном» варианте, и, следовательно, с равным успехом может быть обособлено.

Comment: Уже совсем скоро все умы без исключения будут разбираться в тонических ударениях (это будет приравниваться к умению читать).  Вот, к примеру,  новый синтаксис русского языка для вузов, и в нем можно, например, прочитать: "БСП, интонация нисходяще-нисходящая с полным понижением голоса в конце первой части". Музыка, да и только. И это не фонетика, как раньше,  а обычная практическая грамматика.

Comment: Далее по теме.  Из предложения можно опустить "в свою очередь", и оно немедленно опять перестроится на две другие фразы (неужели этого никто не видит!), а вот нагромождать несколько обстоятельств в начале предложения не получится  - конструкция перестает читаться, сопротивляясь такому насилию.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хотелось бы последовать совету  и обособлять выражение  "в свою очередь" как можно чаще, но не получается. Достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус, чтобы увидеть, как часто используется необособленный вариант.

В то же время можно согласиться с тем, что анализ смыслового значения выражения - это напрасная трата времени. Всё решает интонационно-грамматическая структура предложения. Если сочетание можно встроить в простое предложение, то обособлять не надо, в противном же случае обособленный оборот можно считать как вводным словом, так и обособленным обстоятельством, разницы нет. Иногда достаточно добавить в предложение одно-два слова или что-то в нем переставить,  и уже потребуется обособление.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Я в свою очередь тоже оттаяла, ожила... Они в свою очередь сдавали торговые места в субаренду. В свою очередь остановились конные и пешие, лучники и панцирники и все остальные, включая и колонну пленных. Максим ещё в детстве слушал его пластинки, Володя в свою очередь всегда восхищался его талантом.

2)Король Иордании, в свою очередь, заявил,что... Это, в свою очередь, способствовало бы возникновению доверия в обществе. Володя, в свою очередь, вспоминал, что как-то раз он услышал колокола в церкви...

3) Парный вариант в начале предложения: А) В свою очередь у России есть и конкретные национальные интересы. Б) В свою очередь, предприниматели готовы платить налоги, помогать правительству бороться с бедностью...

Comment: > Очень хотелось бы последовать совету и обособлять выражение "в свою очередь" как можно чаще, но не получается. Достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус, чтобы увидеть, как часто используется необособленный вариант.

Мне кажется, частотность не свидетельствует ни о положительности, ни об отрицательности характера того или иного феномена. В частности, в данном случае это свидетельствует лишь о том, что те, кто работал над пунктуационным оформлением представленных в Национальном корпусе текстов, не испытывают затруднений в разграничении вводных слов и членов предложения.

Comment: Мы же испытываем, поэтому я решила поделиться своими наблюдениями.

>Если сочетание можно встроить в простое предложение

Прошу прощения, что Вы имеете в виду?