# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "в свою очередь"?

Tags: запятые

*Программа курсов поделена на разделы, а они в свою очередь включают в себя задачи.*

Comment: Максим, примите ответ Бегемотуса, пожалуйста, ведь оказалось, что я неправильно ответил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, здесь нужно обособление.
"В свою очередь" - здесь вводное сочетание.
Этот случай хорошо разобран в "Письмовнике" портала "Грамота.ру".
Приведу полностью, чтобы не пересказывать.

> В СВОЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ, вводное сочетание
>
> Указывает на то, что данное высказывание связано по смыслу с
> предшествующим. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях
> см. в Прил. 2.
>
> Куда бежать – Колька не знал, потому что дальше своей улицы нигде не
> бывал, но это желание в нем росло и крепло с каждым днем. Сапожник, в
> свою очередь, отлично знал, как бегают новички ученики, и зорко следил
> за Колькой. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, В каменном колодце. В центре было
> круглое белое здание, окруженное широким черным кольцом. Черное
> кольцо, в свою очередь, было опоясано золотисто-желтым кольцом… Н.
> Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе.
>
> ! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «со
> своей стороны, в ответ, когда наступила очередь»).
>
> «Ты, Ветер, много хвастаешься», – заметила в свою очередь старая
> Белка. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Лесная сказка. Ася вопросительно посмотрела
> на меня. Я в свою очередь протянул ей руку и на этот раз крепко пожал
> ее холодные пальчики. И. Тургенев, Ася.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_112

Вряд ли в нашем примере можно трактовать как член предложения - смысл не тот.

(+) ===

Признаюсь, мне отчего-то казалось, что даже для этого значения оборота (т.е. связующего элемента) обособление его факультативно. Но "грамота"  безапелляционна, приходится верить.

(+) ===

Поскольку совершенно неожиданно для меня вопрос оказался дискуссионным, даю еще две значимые ссылки.

[В свою очередь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4657)

и Розенталь -

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

Comment: Да, не сверился я с источниками. Но всё же я не очень понимаю разницу между предложением Максима и последним примером без обособления: *...посмотрела на **меня. Я** в свою очередь...*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Именно не понимаете - или хотите поспорить с "Грамотой"? Если первое, то это странно. Там же значение иное. У Максима нет реальной очереди, все это происходит одновременно. Цепочка (очередь) только в рассуждениях. А у Тургенева - сначала Ася (что-то там сделала), а потом уж я - второй, так сказать, очередью. Здесь есть некая аналогия со словом "наконец", которое тоже бывает вводным (при цепочке рассуждений) и членом предложения (в случае реальной очереди). И тем самым требует разной пунктуации...

Comment: Ну а если вы хотите убедить (меня или "Грамоту") в том, что нет разницы, то давайте отложим на два-три дня. Я сегодня и без того эмоционально перегружен...

Comment: *Ну а если вы хотите убедить...* Конечно не хочу! Вы всё по полочкам разложили, и теперь я понял разницу.)) Хотел удалить ответ, но не получается, потому что он принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Обособлять "в свою очередь" не вижу здесь никаких причин.

Answer (score 1):

(1) ***Программа курсов поделена на разделы, а они в свою очередь включают в себя задачи.***

(2) ***Программа курсов поделена на разделы, а они,  в свою очередь,  включают в себя задачи.***

Обособление факультативное.

1. Это не вводное слово, так как не относится к тематике вводных слов и входит в состав предложение на правах структурного элемента. Если считать, что это вводное слово, то оно должно  иметь значение «оформление мыслей»,  но это **не очень похоже на оформительскую функцию.**
2. Это наречное выражение, обособление зависит от желания автора выделить и подчеркнуть оборот. Я бы здесь выделила в качестве частотного решения только последовательность **реальных действий во времени** – эти наречия обычно не обособляются:  *Ася вопросительно посмотрела на меня. Я в свою очередь протянул ей руку и на этот раз крепко пожал ее холодные пальчики.*
3. Для проверки статуса оборота желательно подобрать синоним к «в свою очередь», мне таким синонимом кажется присоединительный союз ТАКЖЕ, а он как раз является членом предложения.  Например: Шкаф разделен на полки,  они также (= в свою очередь) делятся на отдельные секции.
4. В Нацкорпусе  наречное выражение как обособляется, так и не обособляется.

Примеры:

**В свою очередь** у России есть и конкретные национальные интересы. [Ю. В. Федотов. Ответы на вопросы корреспондента ИТАР-ТАСС в преддверии основной ежегодной сессии ЭКОСОС 2004 года // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004]

**В свою очередь** нефинансовые активы состоят из произведённых и непроизведенных активов. [Национальное богатство республики Бурятия // «Вопросы статистики», 2004]

Вегетативная нервная система, **в свою очередь,** также состоит из двух частей ― симпатической и парасимпатической. [Валерия Фейгина. Все болезни от нервов // «100% здоровья», 2003.01.15]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119645/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).

Answer (score 1):

Сошлюсь для большей ясности на "Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений" Остроумовой О.А. и Фрамполь О.Д.

> **В CBOЮ ОЧЕРЕДЬ**, наречное выражение.
>
> 1. Редко употребляется в функции вводного в значении  «последовательность» (указывает на порядок мыслей):  *Независимость, в
>    свою очередь, является синонимом свободы*  (В. Набоков).
> 2. Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства  образа действия (= в ответ, со своей стороны; указывает на  реальную
>    последовательность событий), не обособляется:  *Меня удивляло, что они
>    в свою очередь были благодарны мне  за то, что я внимательно их слушаю*
>    (К. Паустовский); *А вы? -  в свою очередь спросила Катя* (И. Тургенев);
>    *Троицкий в свою  очередь разглядывал меня не без уважения* (С. Довлатов).
>
> Часто обособляется при желании автора придать выражению особую
> значимость, интонационно выделяется: *Откинув брезент, он вынул из нее
> несколько пакетов и бросил, в свою очередь, пачку писем* (А. Грин);
> *Наверное,  из-за этого, хотя и с некоторыми предосторожностями, Ясона
> пускали в  дом, и он, в свою очередь, терпел поучения родственников*
> (Ф. Искандер).
>
> Есть тенденция обособлять это выражение, если оно
> находится в  обособленном обороте или после союза, союзного слова
> (т. е. на месте разрыва  сочетания слов с сильной синтаксической
> связью): *Чаша была упакована в  коробочку, находившуюся, в свою
> очередь, в другой коробке* (В. Набоков); *Ни  розу не взглянув на меня,
> она прочла записку, обернулась и, в свою очередь,  позвала...*
> (К. Паустовский); *Я тотчас же смекнул, что птичка сама летит  в сетку,
> и, в свою очередь, приготовился* (Ф. Достоевский); З*ина вспыхнула  и
> сверкающими глазами посмотрела на Марью Александровну, которая, в
> свою очередь, разрывалась от злости* (Ф. Достоевский).

Comment: @grizlli вы конечно можете заявить нежелании спорить, но я очень прошу пояснить, чем это ваше правило от Остроумовой и Фрамполь отличается от сказанного у Розенталя? И вообще зачем вы его привели, если оно только подтверждает ошибочность пунктуации во всех ваших примерах?

Comment: ПС. Хотелось бы, конечно, посмотреть на контекст у Довлатова. Потому как все остальное - вполне по Розенталю.

Comment: ППС. А ну естественно. У Довлатова - как раз тот сучай, когда обособлять не надо. Там четкая последовательность действий. Сначала с одним ("редактором") пообщался, потом уже Троицкий - в свою очередь. Просто удивляюсь, как можно с таким апломбом приводить аргументы одназначно доказывающие именно ошибочность своей же логики.

Comment: @grizlli Огромное спасибо, очень интересная словарная статья,  к тому же она полностью отвечает моему мнению по этой теме. Очень важно, что там названо значение вводности для наречия «в свою очередь» –  в этом случае оно указывает на порядок изложения мысли. Неудивительно, что это значение встречается редко. В остальных же случаях мы имеем факультативное обособление  наречного выражения по обычным правилам.

Comment: @Марк Из Я полагаю, что в чат нужно переместить все комментарии, особенно такие: "Просто удивляюсь, как можно с таким АПЛОМБОМ приводить аргументы одназначно доказывающие именно ошибочность своей же логики".  В любом случае grizlli вот уже два дня нет на форуме, и  мне кажется вполне уместным извиниться перед ним если не участнику, то хотя бы модераторам за все, что здесь было написано. Оставить нужно только мою благодарность, причем не дежурную, а самую искреннюю.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

**О «Справочнике по пунктуации» и вводных словах вообще**

1. **Справочник мне давно знаком**, у меня есть его бумажный вариант  2012 года в издательстве ЭКСМО, теперь он в электронном виде присутствует на Грамоте.ру.  Далее цитирую слова нашего участника:  «Признаюсь, мне отчего-то казалось, что даже для этого значения оборота (т.е. связующего элемента) обособление его факультативно. Но **"грамота" безапелляционна, приходится верить».**
2. А я вот верить не хочу, это не мой принцип. **С каких это пор вполне заурядный справочник стал вдруг законом.** Его что, академики составляли?  Вроде бы нет. Рецензенты именитые? Но рецензенты – это не составители. Для меня Розенталь более авторитетен, я его считаю единственным проводником наследия Правил 1956 года, в составлении которых академики как раз принимали активное участие.

Я часто пользуюсь этим справочником,  но чисто в ознакомительном порядке (меня обычно интересует подбор примеров в нем). **Но мне не по душе его категоричность**, то есть безапелляционность,  весьма далекая от гибкости и вариативности по Розенталю, да и **тему вводных слов они трактуют сомнительно.**

3. Кажется, что **определение водности там не учитывается вовсе,** а это очень важно. Вводность – это особая  функция,  так как вводные слова не входят в текст сообщения, а обозначают отношение к сказанному или участвуют в оформление текста (во-первых, во-вторых, следовательно, кроме того и т.д.). Это не сама речь, а ее второй план, метки-указатели для содержания.

В нашем же случае «в свою очередь»  является **структурным элементом в составе предложения,** так как определяет отношения между его частями. Если речь идет о внутренней структуре чего-либо, то наречие указывает **на подобие**  в его строении или вообще на подобие в чем-либо. Это не оформление речи, а само содержание речи, **так какое же это вводное слово, как уверяет нас справочник.**

Но очень многие  вводным словом называют  любое обособленное наречное выражение, и вероятно, составители справочника как раз из этих людей.

4. Так зачем я буду верить кому-то, читать чужие мнения, сравнивать и сопоставлять их. **Пусть авторы докажут вводность на основании определения вводности, тогда это будет дело.**  И вот   "Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений" Остроумовой О.А. и Фрамполь О.Д. в этом отношении выглядит намного убедительнее.

В комментарии я уже писала отзыв о нем:

Очень важно, что там названо значение вводности для наречия «в свою очередь» – в этом случае оно **указывает на порядок изложения мысли**. Неудивительно, что **это значение встречается редко**. В остальных же случаях мы имеем **факультативное обособление** наречного выражения по обычным правилам. Именно поэтому **в приведенном примере обособления нет,** что соответствует структуре заданного предложения.

Comment: Sharon, не хотите ответить на мой последний вопрос про заряд?

Comment: Артем, очень хочу, вот прямо сейчас и отвечу. Только вы мне в другой раз адрес оставляйте.