# В каких предложениях нет пунктуационных ошибок перед или после "В свою очередь?"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Данный вердикт означает, что на странице присутствует обфусцированный JavaScript-код, который после выполнения подгружает скрипт, который **в свою очередь**  добавляет на страницу тег фрейма.

При размещении задания клиент видит список исполнителей, которые оказывают нужную услугу. **В свою очередь** партнеры получают предложение откликнуться на задание.

Черное кольцо, **в свою очередь**, было опоясано золотисто-желтым кольцом.

Ирина тоскливо повернула голову прочь от него, как бы желая, **в свою очередь,** спрятать от него свое лицо, и положила ее на стол.

Рабочие благодарили своих шефов за помощь и просили почаще их навещать; **в свою очередь**, представители шефской организации приглашали рабочих на заседание художественного совета театра.

Comment: Вопрос актуальный, обсуждался уже на форуме в 2014 году, но мнения были разные  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/В-свою-очередь  Интересно будет послушать, как решают задачу в 2023 году

Comment: Также  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463533/Нужно-ли-выделить-запятыми-в-свою-очередь    https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473641/Обособление-оборота-в-первую-очередь-в-середине-предложения

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, **обсуждения не получилось**: только один ответ, но нет по нему ни голосов, ни комментариев. Вероятно, больше и не будет...

**Загадочная тема вводных слов!** Сколько существует разных правил и методик! Вводные слова обсуждаются всюду и всегда, пользователи **прилежно следуют инструкциям,** а решения не совпадают. Да и при составлении любого текста часто приходится определяться: вводное слово или нет? Вот уж действительно вещь в себе!

Эту картину мы видим и в данном случае: обозначено мнение автора вопроса, ответа, но вот по некоторым предложениям вывод неоднозначный. Прежде всего,  это касается двух первых предложений. Там ситуации похожие, но, **как мне думается**, решения разные. Также предложение 4 под сомнением.

**Решение**

1. *Данный вердикт означает, что на странице присутствует обфусцированный JavaScript-код, который после выполнения подгружает скрипт, который **в свою очередь** добавляет на страницу тег фрейма.*

Здесь обозначена очередность **реальных** действий. Мы видим работу  двух структур (кода и скрипта): они  как бы соблюдают очередь (прямое значение слова) и действуют последовательно. Это **наречие**, нет обособления.

**Структура** предложения соответствует такому решению, то есть сочетание вписывается в предложение, интонация корректная. Кроме того, там обособление нежелательно ввиду распространенности всего предложения и большого количества запятых.

2. *При размещении задания клиент видит список исполнителей, которые оказывают нужную услугу. **В свою очередь**,  партнеры получают предложение откликнуться на задание.*

Здесь, как я думаю, **другая ситуация**: клиент со своим заданием, управляющая система и ряд исполнителей. Клиент размещает задание, система сразу оповещает об этом всех исполнителей, то есть каждый исполнитель получает это задание. Поэтому сочетание обозначает **соответствие** всех действий, а не их прямую последовательность.

Это **вводное слово**, обозначающее **очередность рассуждения** автора при описании. Можно заменить вводным словом ***«соответственно»***.  Автор размещает сочетание в начале предложения, что характерно для обычной позиции вводного слова.

4. *Литвинов пошатнулся, словно кто его в грудь ударил. Ирина тоскливо повернула голову прочь от него, как бы желая, **в свою очередь,**  спрятать от него свое лицо, и положила ее на стол*.

Это **вводное слово**, обозначающее **очередность мыслей** при рассуждении, но не реальную очередь. Значение **переносное**, переосмыслено автором.

**Дополнение**

Задачи в теме вводных слов не решаются стандартным методом **подстановки**, здесь при анализе нужно учитывать целый **комплекс факторов**: семантику, грамматическую структуру, интонацию и даже графику письма. Но при составлении текста опытный пользователь не проводит такого анализа, а делает выбор интуитивно, задумываясь только иногда.

У меня расхождение с заданными примерами только **в предложении 2,** которое является спорным при решении задачи **по семантике**: очередность здесь можно понимать по-разному. В **прямом** значении слова это наречие. Но если это значение **соответствия** в действии нескольких структур, то это вводное слово.

Тогда можно посмотреть **структуру** необособленного варианта и обозначить ударения и паузы: *В свою очередь / партнеры получают предложЕние / откликнуться на задАние.* Я вижу здесь три смысловых отрезка, разделенных произносительными паузами. Если подчеркнуть первую паузу, то это будет вводное слово. Именно поэтому вводные сочетания в начале предложения обычно **обособляются.**

Однозначный выбор сложно сделать, поэтому пусть это будет **авторский выбор.**

Answer (score 0):

**В первом предложении** запятая  нужна перед и после **«В свою очередь».**  Так как оно является вводным словом. Мы видим, что сочетание является вводным.  В этом случае оно выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.  Здесь  нельзя  по смыслу  заменить  словосочетаниями «От себя» или «в ответ» Больше подойдет, например, "в то же время", или "затем" или "после этого".
Например:

**Иван, в свою очередь, думал, что легко справится с поставленной задачей.*

*Эта компания, в свою очередь, отличается тем, что всегда выполняет работу в заранее оговоренные сроки.*

**Во втором предложении** также нужна запятая после «В свою очередь». Здесь  оно также является вводным словом.  Здесь нельзя заменить по смыслу словами или словосочетаниями "От себя" или "В ответ"  И опять можно заменить словом "затем" , например.

**В третьем предложении**  «в свою очередь»  правильно выделено  запятыми,  это слово вводное.  Здесь словосочетание  **"В свою очередь"** можно просто выбросить из предложения без потери смысла.

**В четвертом  предложении** запятые не нужны, так как  здесь  речь идет о том что Ирина  желала  "от себя"  спрятать кольцо.  Это не вводное слово, оно часть предложения.  Ирина "в ответ" "от себя".
Если **«в свою очередь»** — член предложения и выражает значение «в ответ»  «от себя» или «по наступлении своей очереди», то запятая не требуется: ни перед, ни после словосочетания.
Например:

*Он выслушал его точку зрения и в свою очередь хотел быть поделиться своим мнением.*

*Парни пригласили девушек сходить в кинотеатр, а девушки в свою очередь предложили сходить в ресторан.*

*Молодой человек, встаньте в свою очередь.*

*Мать отчитала сына за то, что он поздно вернулся, отец же в свою очередь промолчал.*

Можно подставить «со своей стороны», «когда настал черёд», значит, перед нами наречное выражение

**В пятом предложении**  **«в свою очередь»**  правильно выделено запятыми.. Здесь оно вводное слово.  Здесь также по смыслу нельзя  заменить  «от себя»,  например.

Предложение, кстати, можно и переделать.

***В то же время партнеры получают предложение откликнуться на задание.***

Пример предложений:

**Наступил сентябрь, и, в свою очередь, распахнулись двери школ, университетов и других образовательных учреждений.*

*Клетка состоит из молекул, последние же, в свою очередь, состоят из атомов.**

Comment: Насчёт второго предложения я бы не стал однозначно утверждать.

Comment: @Серж Интересные предложения для разбора. Я рассуждаю иначе, и у меня получается такой результат: везде вводные слова, кроме 1 (там наречие). В предложении (2) вводное слово. Здесь нет "очереди", два действия происходят одновременно, а не последовательно.

Comment: @Sharon, почему мне кажется во втором предложении нужна запятая. Они получают откликнуться на задание, когда наступает их очередь. Возможно, ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Серж  Я дам объяснение в поле ответа, так удобнее.